# Make Web Browser control communicate with VB.NET Program

Tags: vb.net, html, user-interface

What I am looking for here is a way to possibly click a button inside a web browser control and have it call a sub from inside the program or have the program react to something on the page.

I am trying to make a HTML5 GUI for my application. I don't really want use any 3rd party API's to handle commands from a HTML5 interface but if I can find another alternative that would be good. But if there is no other way I would be content with using a 3rd party API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I have done this in the past is to specify a special protocol for my app.

```
yourapp:somefunction/someparameter
```

Handle [the `Navigating` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigating.aspx), and in your code for when that event is fired, check to see if the URL has your protocol on the front of it.  If it is, set `e.Cancel = true` to cancel navigation, and add code to handle the URL parameters yoruself.

Comment: Seeing as I am really against IE would this same thing work with the WebKit.NET API?

Comment: It appears so, according to their documentation:  http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/docs/

Comment: Also, would you be able to give me some links on creating and using a custom protocol? Or some example code would be nice too.

Comment: @The_Amateur_Programmer, I provided an example in my answer.  Parse the string however you need to.  It's hard to suggest anything more specific... I have no idea what your needs are.

Comment: It's all good. You've explained everything. I know what I need to do now.